# Laravel, Vue.js Insert Array

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have an array and an id of another table. I need each array item to be a new record. Each of these records needs to include one item from the array and the id of the other table. How do I make the store function loop through the array and each time grab the other table id and insert into the database?

The View

```
<tablv>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>MFG</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="hp in ordered_handpieces">
             <td>
                <input type="checkbox" :value="hp.id" v-model="hp_id"><span>{{hp.mfg.mfg_name}}</span>
             </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

The Script

```
        data: function() {
                return {
                    hp_wo_id:'',
                    hp_id:[],
                    }
            },

        methods: {
               onSubmit(){
                 axios.post('/hp_wo_unit', this.$data)   
                
                 }    
            
            }
```

The Controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
        foreach (request(['hp_id']) as $hp_id) {
            hp_wo_unit::create(request(['hp_wo_id'],$hp_id));
        }
    return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said each on of them to be a new record, here's a simple approach for what you said :

```
foreach (request(['hp_id']) as $item) {
    hp_wo_unit::create(request(['hp_wo_id'],$item));
    // Or 
    $hp = new MODEL();
    $hp->hp_wo_id = request(['hp_wo_id']);
    $hp->hp_id = $item;
    $hp-save();
    
}
```

Comment: I added more of the View. Please see above.  With your suggestion I am getting one record regardless of array length and the array values are not inserting into the database.

Comment: Yes. It seems like it should work but it does not. I am getting one record regardless of array length and the array value is not inserting into the database. I added the view just in case that is where the problem might be. Thanks!

Comment: @T.A.return $request and show me the response. idk about your view, since it's looking fine. just show me the response.

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but I am not sure where to view the response. How do I see the response in a Vue.js application?

Comment: open your page, then use `ctrl+i` or inspect element, then go in Network tab, and you can see network calls from there. when you hit submit button 1 request call should be added, click on it and go to response tab.

Comment: Here is the response:"hp_id":[21,24], "hp_wo_id":5082

Comment: Show me base on my solution what you actually code in store method. edit your question and put the updated code there.